# Inno Setup: Run external driver installer only if its component is checked

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I want to create an user-friendly setup installer for my application.

Actually it's very basic:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Application
AppVersion=2.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\MyApplication
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyApp.exe
OutputDir=userdocs:MyApp
SetupIconFile=icon.ico
UninstallIconFile=icon.ico

[Components]
Name: "program"; Description: "Program Files"; Types: full compact custom; Flags: fixed
Name: "driver"; Description: "Driver files"; Types: full
Name: "driver\USB"; Description: "USB-Driver"; Types: full; Flags: checkablealone
Name: "driver\MISC"; Description: "MISC-Driver"; Types: full ;Flags: checkablealone

[Files]
Source: "*.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: program
Source: "*.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: program
Source: "*.bmp"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: program
Source: "*.ini"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: program
Source: "USBDriver.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: driver\usb
Source: "MiscDriver.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: driver\misc

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\USBDriver.exe"; Description: "Install USB-Driver"; Flags: postinstall skipifdoesntexist
Filename: "{app}\MiscDriver.exe"; Description: "Install Misc-Driver"; Flags: postinstall skipifdoesntexist runascurrentuser


[Icons]
Name: "{commonprograms}\MyApp"; Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"
Name: "{commondesktop}\MyApp"; Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"
```

The user should decide if he wants to install the both drivers.
For that I created the two `[Run]` section entries.

After the installation, the driver installation should start. 
Actually it's buggy there. I got a problem if I checked no driver installation component, or just one of them. Nevertheless the installer still runs both setup files I got to choose after installation.

How could I start the driver installation only if the user checked its component for installation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It means that I can see both checkboxes on the "Finished" page, if I just installed one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to filter the `[Run]` section entries using [the `Components` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=componentstasksparams), the same way you filter the entries in the `[Files]` section already:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\USBDriver.exe"; Description: "Install USB-Driver"; \
    Components: driver\usb; Flags: postinstall
Filename: "{app}\MiscDriver.exe"; Description: "Install Misc-Driver"; \
    Components: driver\misc; Flags: postinstall runascurrentuser
```

---

Note that I've removed the `skipifdoesntexist` flag as I suppose it was your attempt to solve the problem. In general you should not use it, as its only effect is:

> If this flag is specified in the `[Run]` section, Setup won't display an **error message** if `Filename` doesn't exist.

---

If you want to run the installers always, when they are installed, just remove [the `postinstall` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=postinstall) and replace the `Description` parameter with the `StatusMsg` parameter.

You also probably do not want to copy the installers to the `{app}` at all. Install them to the `{tmp}` and use [the `deleteafterinstall` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=deleteafterinstall) to have the main installer remove them after the installation.

```
[Files]
Source: "USBDriver.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Components: driver\usb; Flags: deleteafterinstall
Source: "MiscDriver.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Components: driver\misc; Flags: deleteafterinstall

[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\USBDriver.exe"; StatusMsg: "Installing USB-Driver"; \
    Components: driver\usb; Flags: runasoriginaluser
Filename: "{tmp}\MiscDriver.exe"; StatusMsg: "Installing Misc-Driver"; \
    Components: driver\misc
```

*(Without the `postinstall` flag, the default is the `runascurrentuser`, hence I switched the flags).*

Comment: Thanks @Martin Prikryl that solved my problem. Is it now possible to start the driver installation after the program installation? So that I don't have to mark the checkbox on the "Finished" page?